# Difference between net.nf_conntrack_max and net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max

Tags: linux, netfilter

Does anybody knows the difference between `net.nf_conntrack_max` and `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max`?

I have found no related documents on the Internet about the relation between the two sysctl keys.

Answer (score 2):

No difference whatsoever. Both names control the same internal value. (Writing to one will change both.)